# Scrapy Spider Does Not Scrape Page 1

Tags: scrapy

I want my spider to scrape the listings on every page of a website. I used CrawlSpider and LinkExtractor. But when I looked at the csv file, nothing on the first page (i.e. start url) was scraped. The scraped items started from page 2. I tested my crawler on the Scrapy shell and it seemed fine. I can't figure out where the problem lies. Below is my spider code. Please help. Thanks a lot!

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from shputuo.items_shputuo import ShputuoItem


class Shputuo(CrawlSpider):
    name = "shputuo"

    allowed_domains = ["shpt.gov.cn"] # DO NOT use www in allowed domains
    start_urls =  ["http://www.shpt.gov.cn/gb/n6132/n6134/n6156/n7110/n7120/index.html"] 

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(), restrict_xpaths=("//div[@class = 'page']/ul/li[5]/a",)), callback="parse_items", follow= True),
)    

    def parse_items(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath("//div[@class = 'neirong']/ul/li"):
            item = ShputuoItem()
            word = sel.xpath("a/text()").extract()[0]
            item['id'] = word[3:11]
            item['title'] = word[11:len(word)]
            item['link'] = "http://www.shpt.gov.cn" + sel.xpath("a/@href").extract()[0]
            item['time2'] = sel.xpath("span/text()").extract()[0][1:11]

            request = scrapy.Request(item['link'], callback = self.parse_content)
            request.meta['item'] = item            

            yield request

    def parse_content(self, response):
        item = response.meta['item']
        item['question'] = response.xpath("//div[@id = 'ivs_content']/p[2]/text()").extract()[0]
        item['question'] = "".join(map(unicode.strip, item['question'])) # get rid of unwated spaces and others
        item['reply'] =  response.xpath("//div[@id = 'ivs_content']/p[3]/text()").extract()[0]
        item['reply'] = "".join(map(unicode.strip, item['reply']))
        item['agency'] = item['reply'][6:10]
        item['time1'] = "2015-" + item['question'][0] + "-" + item['question'][2]


        yield item
```

Comment: is the url inside `start_urls` page 1?

Comment: @eLRuLL, yes. It is Page 1.

Answer (score 1):

looks like what you really need to do is to parse elements of the `start_urls` requests and not to only follow the rules.

For that use the `parse_start_url` method which is the callback by default of the `start_urls` requests.